# Cracking the coding interview 2.1 remove duplicate values from singly linked list javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, infinite-loop, singly-linked-list

```
class LinkedListNode {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

let head = new LinkedListNode("head");

let x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 10, 10, 3, 10, 9, 5, 5, 5, 8];

for (let ele of x) {
    let y = new LinkedListNode(ele);
    let pointer = head;
    while (pointer.next != null) {
        pointer = pointer.next;
    }
    pointer.next = y;
}
```

Can someone explain why the following 'solution' leads to an infinite loop?

```
let removeDup = function(sll) {
    let array = []
    let pointer = sll;
    while (pointer) {
        if (array.includes(pointer.value)){
        } else {
            array.push(pointer.value);
            sll.next = pointer;
            sll = sll.next;
        }
        pointer = pointer.next;
    }
}
```

It appears that if I

```
let pointer = sll.next;
```

or

```
let array = [sll.value]
```

then it works fine but if I run it as is then it leads to an infinite loop. I can see why it may make a linked list with 2 duplicates of the first value but I can't understand why it makes an infinite loop. Alternatively, if anyone can point me in the right direction for debugging this then that would be appreciated also!

Comment: `sll.next = pointer;` so, with `pointer = sll`, then you make the next node the same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you end up defining a node that references itself within your else condition.

You may be looking for something like this:

```js
class LinkedListNode {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

let head = new LinkedListNode("head");

let x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 10, 10, 3, 10, 9, 5, 5, 5, 8];

for (let ele of x) {
    let y = new LinkedListNode(ele);
    let pointer = head;
    while (pointer.next != null) {
        pointer = pointer.next;
    }
    pointer.next = y;
}

function removeDup(currentNode = sll) {
 const seen = {};
 let lastUnique;
 while (currentNode) {
  if (seen[currentNode.value]) {
   lastUnique.next = currentNode.next;
  } else {
   seen[currentNode.value] = true;
   lastUnique = currentNode;
  }
  currentNode = currentNode.next;
 }
}

removeDup(head);

let outputNode = head;
while (outputNode) {
 outputNode = outputNode.next;
 if (outputNode) {
  console.log(outputNode.value);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How to investigate your bug

You can use a debugger, but for primitive people like me, you can also use console.log

- In case of infinite loop, what you want is to break free

```
let count = 0
while (pointer && count++<5) {
  //whatever
}
```

Even if you fail in your algorithm you will still exit

- Output your variable

Be creative and spam console.log wherever you see fit. put some string to remind you what junk you outputed

```
while (pointer) {
  if (array.includes(pointer.value)){
    console.log('cached skip')
  } else {
    console.log('pointervalue', pointer.value)
    array.push(pointer.value);
    sll.next = pointer;
    sll = sll.next;
    console.log('sllendloop', sll)
  }
  pointer = pointer.next;
}
```

2. Fixing your code

Note: do not use array for cache because it is O(n) look

You may use a Set (O(1)) instead

```js
const removeDup = function(sll) {
  const dupes = new Set()
  let cur = { next: null }
  // you can also as you suggested initialize cur as sll
  // in which case you must mark it as "consumed" idem add the value to dupes
  let sllIter = sll
  while (sllIter) {
    if (dupes.has(sllIter.value)) {
      // early continue to avoid nesting else
      // subjective preference
      sllIter = sllIter.next
      continue
    }
    dupes.add(sllIter.value)
    // link our node to the currently being iterated node
    cur.next = sllIter;

    // advance our node
    cur = sllIter

    // advance iter
    sllIter = sllIter.next
  }
  return sll
}
const l = (value, next) => ({ value, next })
const sllStr = ({ value: a, next: b }) => b ? `${a} -> ${sllStr(b)}`: a
const sll = l(1, l(1, l(2, l(1, l(2, l(3))))))
console.log(sllStr(removeDup(sll))) // 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Comment: I tried using console.log but the developer tools on chrome just froze instead of logging any values. I will try using sets, thanks!

Comment: it won't freeze if you exit in case of infinite loop ensure you add the max iteration count condition

Answer (score 0):

You may write a micro Linked List library perhaps. Here is one with function descriptions;

- `toList`   : takes an array converts it into a list
- `foldList` : Something like reduce. Takes a list, a function and an accumulator.
- `sum`      : takes a list and gives it's sum :)
- `prt`      : pretty print a list
- `nub`      : remove dupes from a list.

```js
function List(e){
  this.data = e;
  this.next = null;
}

List.fromArray = function([a,...as]){
                   var h = new List(a),
                       t = as.reduce((l,e) => [l[0],l[1].next = new List(e)], [h,h]);
                   return t[0];
                 };
List.prototype.fold = function (f,a){
                        var newa = f(a, this.data);
                        return this.next ? this.next.fold(f, newa)
                                         : newa
                      };
List.prototype.log = function(){
                       return this.fold((a,e) => a + e + " -> ", "") + "null";
                     };
List.prototype.nub = function(){
                       var o = this.fold((a,e) => (a[e] = e, a), {}),
                           a = Object.values(o);
                       return List.fromArray(a);
                     }

var arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 10, 10, 3, 10, 9, 5, 5, 5, 8],
    lst = List.fromArray(arr),
    sum = l => l.fold((a,e) => a + e, 0), // just for fun
    res = lst.nub().log();

console.log(res);
```

`nub` is O(n).